# Laravel relationship confustion

Tags: laravel-5, relationship

I am a bit confused with Laravel and relationships in general.

I have 2 tables:

1. coffees with fields: id, name, blend (int(1))
2. blends with fields: id, blend_id (Will be id from coffees table), coffee_id (Will be id from coffees table), percent

If the blend field value is 1, it is a blend and it should have a few records on the blends table.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Which relationships do I have here (belongsTo, hasMany, not sure)
2. How do I get all the coffees for a blend ordered by their names.

In my models I have:
Coffee:

```
public function blend()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Blend', 'blend_id');
}
```

Blend:

```
public function coffee()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Coffee');
}
```

Got a bit lost here, thx

Comment: `How do I get all the coffees for a blend ordered by their names.` make no sens because blend has just one coffee !! or not ??

Comment: Not, a blend can have many coffees, e.g., a blend could have: Coffee A 30%, Coffee B 30%. Edited my question to make it more clear

Comment: And what about coffee, it can have one or more blends ?

Comment: Coffee can have many blends.
X blend can be made with: 50% coffee A, 50% coffee B   Y blend can be made with: 25% coffee A, 25% coffee B, 50% coffee C